# How to Create Artifacts feed in Azure DevOps only with dll

Tags: nuget, azure-artifacts

I have found that we can create private Artifact feed in Azure DevOps pipeline  by `build`, `Pack` and `Push` task in `YAML` Pipeline when we have source code.
[image]

But now I have access to one third party dll (but not source code) which will be referred by all other .Net solutions.
Can some one help me how can we create Artifact feed only with the dll and with no source code access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario, you could create Universal Package instead of Nuget with the dll file.

Both Azure CLI and Azure Pipeline task are supported to publish and download Universal Package.

Azure CLI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops

Universal Package task in Azure Pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Choose the dll file as "Path to file(s) to publish"

[image]